Hide timezone from calendar month view?
How can I hide this absolutely useless information making my calendar more cumbersome then it already is?
Using iCloud account, native Calendar app, OS 12.7.4

I actually want 11 letters gone plus 2 letters of padding space. I don't want to see those. They're taking up almost half of the screen in Month View!

OS version?  It’s going go be difficult at best to find someone who shares your opinion on this insomuch as they’ve found a solution/workaround.  Can you explain how a three letter abbreviation for the time zone (a critically necessary component for date calculations) is  as cumbersome to deal with?

Latest version. It is 6 letters, not 3. https://i.postimg.cc/wMzkjmpj/image.png

I actually want 11 letters gone plus 2 letters of padding space

Native macOS Calendar app? What version of macOS?

Do you connect this calendar to an external calendar server such as GCal or the iCloud Calendar service?

Using iCloud account, native Calendar app, OS 12.7.4

Please edit the question with the additional details, also embed any screenshots directly into the text.

It’s not 11 characters, the fist 5 is the time and then the time zone is added. So, at most, you want to remove 6.

I just checked, I don't have any timezone shown in Month view for entries within my own timezone. Did you check whether the calendar entries you create are in the same timezone your computer is set to?
